# Better Alternative than $all with $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb

Here's a sample document of my Mongo DB structure:

```
{ _id: 1
  records: [{n: "Name", v: "Kevin"}, 
            {n: "Age", v: "100"}, 
             ..., 
            {n: "Field25", v: "Value25"} ]
}
```

To search on all documents having `Name of "Kevin" and an Age of "100"`, I'm using **$all** with **$elemMatch**. I need to use $elemMatch's for an exact sub-document match of n: "Name" and v: "Kevin", as well as $all since I'm querying on an **array**.

```
db.collection.find({"records" : { $all: [
                                         {$elemMatch: {n: "Name", v: "Kevin"},
                                         {$elemMatch: {n: "Age", v: "100"}
                                        ]}})
```

However, the $all operator is inefficient when the first $elemMatch argument is non-selective, i.e. there are many documents that match this field.

The Mongo [Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#use-all-with-elemmatch) elaborate:

> In the current release, queries that use the $all operator must scan
>   all the documents that match the first element in the query array. As
>   a result, even with an index to support the query, the operation may
>   be long running, particularly when the first element in the array is
>   not very selective.

Is there a better alternative for my queries?

Comment: with this schema? no.  You can track which of the attributes are more selective and put them first (in fact, weren't *you* the one who recently asked how to do just that)?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an radical change to your structure, and this would simplify the queries. Sorry if this change is not possible, but without more data I do not see any problem with that:

```
{ _id: 1
  records: [{"Name":"Kevin", 
            "Age":"100", 
             ..., 
            "Field25":"Value25"} ]
}
```

And the query:

```
db.collection.find("records":{$elemMatch:{Name:"Kevin","Age":100}})
```

This will return **all the objects that have a record** (assuming there are more records, for example if they are students of a class) **matching all of the conditions mentioned**.

**But** in case you want to have **just a document per _id**, forget about the records array:

```
{ _id: 1,
 "Name":"Kevin", 
 "Age":"100", 
   ..., 
 "Field25":"Value25"} ]
    }
```

and the query:

```
db.collection.find({Name:"Kevin","Age":100})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Originally, I had this database structure, but, due to my heavy indexing requirements, moved to the generic attribute structure - `records.n-records.v`

Comment: Hi Kevin, sorry it did not help, it is difficult to see the need of your structure without further explanation. As you wrote, the use of $all makes your indexes not very useful for your case. I will come back if I find a better approach! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the best solution.

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  records: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$records",
      as: "record",
      cond: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$$record.v",
              "Kevin"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$$record.v",
              "100"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

solution link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/aQAw0cG9Ipm